# Flexbox и Mozilla Firefox, как работает?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, google-chrome, firefox

Нужны ли на сегодняшний момент префиксы или какие-либо изощрения чтобы использовать `flexbox` в Mozilla Firefox?

В Chrome все работает хорошо, а в Mozilla Firefox картинки выезжают из контейнеров.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на подобные вопросы можно искать вот тут: [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) - там проверяется совместимость с текущими версиями большинства браузеров + некоторые старые и будущие версии.
По вашему вопросу - в Файрфокс, как показывает сайт, поддержка полная. так что, вероятно, ваши картинки выезжают по другой причине.

п.с. в любом случае, вендорный префикс для мозилы `-moz-` - быстрее добавить его к свойству и проверить, чем писать вопрос и ждать ответа